# Can not start a new project as unity has "failed to load window layout"

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Clicking "load default layout" does nothing (just rerenders the alert box), clicking "revert factory settings" also does nothing.

I've googled this issue and the common solution is to reopen unity and to reimport all assests except this is a brand new project. There is nothing in it to import.

I've tried creating a new project and it still gives me this error.

I'm running version 2020.1.5f1 and the target platform is Windows 64-bit

Comment: Haven't faced the issue but Unity logs may provide some clue. Editor logs are available here in windows **C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the simple solution if it has yet to be tried would be to uninstall unity and reinstall.
if you have already tried that try updating to a newer version see if unity 2020.3 works to narrow the problem down a bit more. I had the same problem for me I just updated unity to a newer version and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: This was the only solution that solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: I've heard that a reinstall works sometimes, but a reinstall did not work for me. I had to do the steps described by @carmelo343 in order to solve the issue. It probably depends on which file got corrupted.

Comment: There is not even a 2020.3, the latest pre-release ist 2020.2

Answer (score 32):

Quit Unity and do the following:

- Go to "AppData\Roaming\Unity\Editor-5.x\Preferences\Layouts\default" or "~/Library/Preferences/Unity/Editor-5.x/Layouts/default" for mac, delete LastLayout.dwlt and copy Default.wlt
- Paste Default.wlt into the "Library" folder of your project
- Delete CurrentLayout-default.dwlt and rename Default.wlt to CurrentLayout-default.dwlt

Reopen Unity and load the project. The editor should open normally. You should now be able to create new projects as usual too.

Comment: This worked for me too. A reinstall by itself as suggested by the accepted answer did not work for me. It was only when I got rid of the LastLayout.dwlt and replace CurrentLayout-default.dwlt that things started to work. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Works for me on macOS Catalina with Unity 2020.1.6f1

Comment: For everyone, this works, but make sure you don't rename default.wlt to CurrentLayout-default.wlt, you actually have to change the file extension too.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solutions posted by @carmelo343 and @Abhishek Dubey, but it still didn't work. My solution was to create the unity project using an older version (I used 2019.3.12f1), which shouldn't cause that layout error, then change the unity version to 2020.1.5f1 in Unity Hub (see below)

[Unity Hub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gug1H.png)

Answer (score 3):

If the above solutions didn't work for anyone. Try deleting the libraries folder in your project and then open your project. It will reinstall all the packages.

Comment: The "Library" folder, that is. This worked for my 2022.3.10f1 URP project.

Answer (score 2):

1. go to "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Editor-5.x\Preferences\Layouts\default"
2. Copy this file in your project library folder renaming it with "CurrentLayout-default.dwlt" and replace it with the old one.

Worked for me!!

Comment: Was still getting the issue

Comment: That is Windows only

Answer (score 1):

“Failed to load window layout” Error

solution 2022.3.6 and above

close the unityhub first

solution +A

---

1. in directory %AppData%
   delete all roaming/unity and roaming/unityhub directories

---

2. in unityhub locate your unity.exe path manually

---

3. delete your library directory in project

---

4.load your project backup in unity again

---

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++

solution +B

---

1. uninstall unity and unityhub

---

2. in directory %AppData%
   delete all roaming/unity and roaming/unityhub directories

---

3. in programfilesx86 and programfiles
   delete all unity and unityhub directories

---

4.install unityhub
install unity

---

5.in your project, delete your library directory

---

6.load your project again

---

Answer (score 0):

I get this most every time I launch a project in Unity. Then I close and relaunch and all is fine. I am using a personal layout. I am using Unity 2020.1.8f1. These kind of things never happened before 2020 version.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

1. Open your project folder and delete the **CurrentLayout-default.dwlt** file
2. Go to "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Editor-5.x\Preferences\Layouts"
3. Copy **Default.wlt** file to your project library folder and rename it to "CurrentLayout-default.**dwlt**"

my project opened normally without the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downloading and installing the latest Unity Hub.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in 2023. None of these solutions works for me, only `git stash --all`.

I close the editor and run that command to basically remove all `.sln` files, Library folders, etc. And open again.

Answer (score -1):

I saved my project to a different location and was able to open Unity.

Answer (score -1):

just try this : in unity editor: Help -> Check For Updates -> uncheck the Check For Update

Comment: The issue is that Unity doesn't open so I can't go the help tab. I launch unity, the pop up appears, none of the buttons (other than quit) will work as it just relaunches the pop up.

Comment: you click quit button then open project again, or disconnect internet and open your project then do what say above to solve. I solved it like this, if you can't, just try another way you find, there is a way for you